# Gibberish returned from xpath expression

Tags: ios, xpath

I am using thpple to to capture the wave height and wave direction data from this site 
http://www.ehp.qld.gov.au/coastal/monitoring/waves/site.php?siteid=64 to use in an IOS app I am developing. 
They are both contained in strong tags and I am wondering if these are resulting in the gibberish text returned.

The wave height is `‰X#å`.

The wave direction is `‰X#å`.

The xpath expression I am using is:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]//p//strong
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your XPath.  Where's the code where you're using this XPath?

Comment: Thanks JLRishe. You're question resulted in my discovered I was specifying returning a char rather than a string? so the issue is resolved at last. thanks again!